# \chaptermark in tikz header (book design)

Tags: tikz-pgf, fancyhdr, scrbook

How can I add the current chapter and section to the node?

```
\node[color=white, anchor=west] at ($(current page.north west) - (-10ex,3.5ex)$)
{\ifnum\value{chapter}>0 \thechapter.~\chaptermark\fi};
```

`\chaptermark` or `\sectionmark` doesn't work here.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[
  a4paper, top=25mm, bottom=30mm, 
  inner=20mm, outer=70mm,
  marginparsep=7mm, marginparwidth=45mm,
]{geometry}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{myviolet}{HTML}{4c0068}

\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
\fancyhead[ER]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \draw[fill=myviolet!90, draw=none] ($(current page.north west) + (8.5ex,7ex)$) rectangle ($(current page.north east) - (0ex,7ex)$);
    \draw[fill=myviolet, draw=none] ($(current page.north west) + (8ex,7ex)$) rectangle ($(current page.north west) - (0ex,7ex)$);
    \node[color=white] at ($(current page.north west) - (-4ex,3.5ex)$) {\textbf{\Large\thepage}};
    \node[color=white, anchor=west] at ($(current page.north west) - (-10ex,3.5ex)$) {\ifnum\value{chapter}>0 \thechapter.\fi};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\fancyhead[OL]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \draw[fill=myviolet!90, draw=none] ($(current page.north west) + (0,7ex)$) rectangle ($(current page.north east) - (8.5ex,7ex)$);
    \draw[fill=myviolet, draw=none] ($(current page.north east) - (8ex,7ex)$) rectangle ($(current page.north east) + (0ex,7ex)$);
    \node[color=white] at ($(current page.north east) - (4ex,3.5ex)$) {\textbf{\Large\thepage}};
    \node[color=white, anchor=east] at ($(current page.north east) - (10ex,3.5ex)$) {\ifnum\value{section}>0  \thesection.\fi};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test Chapter}
\section{Test Section}    
\lipsum[1-3]    
\newpage    
\section{Test Section 2}    
\lipsum[1-3]    
\newpage    
\section{Test Section 3}   
\lipsum[1-3]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`\chaptermark` sets `\markboth` and then you can use `\leftmark` for the chapter in the header. Similarly, `\sectionmark` sets `\markright`. So `\rightmark` can be used for the section entry in the header.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[
  top=25mm, bottom=30mm, 
  inner=20mm, outer=70mm,
  marginparsep=7mm, marginparwidth=45mm,
]{geometry}

\usepackage{tikz}% loads also xcolor
\definecolor{myviolet}{HTML}{4c0068}

\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
\fancyhead[ER]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \fill[myviolet!90] ([xshift=8.5ex]current page.north west) rectangle ([yshift=-7ex]current page.north east);
    \node[anchor=west] at ([xshift=10ex,yshift=-3.5ex]current page.north west) {\leftmark};
    \fill[myviolet] ([yshift=-7ex]current page.north west) rectangle ([xshift=8ex]current page.north west);
    \node at ([xshift=4ex,yshift=-3.5ex]current page.north west) {\pagemark};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\fancyhead[OL]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \fill[myviolet!90] (current page.north west) rectangle ([xshift=-8.5ex,yshift=-7ex]current page.north east);
    \node[anchor=east] at ([xshift=-8.5ex,yshift=-3.5ex]current page.north east){\rightmark};
    \fill[myviolet] ([xshift=-8ex,yshift=-7ex]current page.north east)rectangle (current page.north east);
    \node at ([xshift=-4ex,yshift=-3.5ex]current page.north east){\pagemark};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

% font for the pagenumber and the head entries
\setkomafont{pagenumber}{\color{white}\bfseries\Large}
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\color{white}\bfseries\Large}

\renewcommand\chaptermark[1]{\markboth{\protect\usekomafont{pageheadfoot}\thechapter\autodot\ #1}{}}
\renewcommand\sectionmark[1]{\markright{\protect\usekomafont{pageheadfoot}\thesection\autodot\ #1}}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test Chapter}
\section{Test Section}    
\lipsum[1-3]    
\newpage    
\section{Test Section 2}    
\lipsum[1-3]    
\newpage    
\section{Test Section 3}   
\lipsum[1-3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

But I think it is better to use `scrlayer-scrpage` (or the older `scrpage2`) together with `scrbook` instead of `fancyhdr`.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[
  top=25mm, bottom=30mm, 
  inner=20mm, outer=70mm,
  marginparsep=7mm, marginparwidth=45mm,
]{geometry}

\setlength\headheight{18pt}% suggested by scrlayer-scrpage
\setlength\footheight{18pt}% suggested by scrlayer-scrpage

\usepackage{tikz}% loads also xcolor
\definecolor{myviolet}{HTML}{4c0068}

\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}% or the older scrpage2
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot
\lehead{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \fill[myviolet!90] ([xshift=8.5ex]current page.north west) rectangle ([yshift=-7ex]current page.north east);
    \node[anchor=west] at ([xshift=10ex,yshift=-3.5ex]current page.north west) {\leftmark};
    \fill[myviolet] ([yshift=-7ex]current page.north west) rectangle ([xshift=8ex]current page.north west);
    \node at ([xshift=4ex,yshift=-3.5ex]current page.north west) {\pagemark};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\rohead{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \fill[myviolet!90] (current page.north west) rectangle ([xshift=-8.5ex,yshift=-7ex]current page.north east);
    \node[anchor=east] at ([xshift=-8.5ex,yshift=-3.5ex]current page.north east){\rightmark};
    \fill[myviolet] ([xshift=-8ex,yshift=-7ex]current page.north east)rectangle (current page.north east);
    \node at ([xshift=-4ex,yshift=-3.5ex]current page.north east){\pagemark};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

% font for the pagenumber and the head entries
\setkomafont{pagenumber}{\color{white}\bfseries\Large}
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\color{white}\bfseries\Large}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test Chapter}
\section{Test Section}    
\lipsum[1-3]    
\newpage    
\section{Test Section 2}    
\lipsum[1-3]    
\newpage    
\section{Test Section 3}   
\lipsum[1-3]

\end{document}
```

[image]